# Symmetric distribution minimizes second moment

Tags: probability-distributions, optimization, symmetric-functions

assuming that I have a probability distribution D with a pdf p(x) symmetric around zero.
Then I guess that this distribution minimizes the second moment, i.e. E_D(X²) is minimal
among all small variations of the distribution D where p(x) is replaced by a not-symmetric pdf.

I hope this is clear. If not, I will try to clarify.
Is there a simple proof for this?

Ciao
Karl

Comment: How do you define "small variations"?

Comment: @ d.k.o. as it is done in the calculus of variations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations